# Render component after keyboard closes or listen to keyboard close event in react app in cordova android

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am migrating a 'work-in-progress' `react.js` application to an android app using `cordova`.
all seems to work fine except for a component that doesnt render itself peoperly when the keyboard closes, the component generally looks like this.
[image]

**Now when you click on an input and close it the view re renders just fine:**
[image]

**But once you fill it and close the keyboard the component doesnt re render itself:**
[image]
[image]

the component just gets stuck like that, the easy solution would obviously be to "force render" by setting the state again, **the issue is that I cant seem to find a way to listen to keyboard changes on this react-cordova app**, also why would the component re render itself when the form is empty but not when its filled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps someone:
in the `component`:
add an empty callback for the window resize event.

```
useEffect(() => {
        window.onresize = function(){
            //console.log("resizing");
        };
    }, []);
```

as well as adding to cordova config.xml:
inside the `widget tab`
`xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` as a property

and:

```
<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application/activity">
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
    </edit-config>
```

as content of the widget.

also:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />`

in the `<head/>` of `public/index.html`